# Understanding surjectivity of $G_{\mathfrak{P}}\to G(\kappa(\mathfrak{P})\mid \kappa(\mathfrak{p}))$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ramification

I'm trying to understand Theorem I.9.4 from Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory* (page 56).

First he proves that $\kappa(\mathfrak{P})\mid \kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ is a normal extension, which is fine with me.

But I'm confused with the proof that  $G_{\mathfrak{P}}\to G(\kappa(\mathfrak{P})\mid \kappa(\mathfrak{p}))$ is surjective.

He talks about a "maximal separable subextension" of $\kappa(\mathfrak{P})\mid \kappa(\mathfrak{p})$. But isn't the extension itself separable? I mean, $\kappa(\mathfrak{p}):=\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}$ is a finite field (because $\mathfrak{o}$ is Dedekind), therefore a perfect field, so any finite extension of it should be separable, right?

Besides, aren't we assuming $\kappa(\mathfrak{P})\mid \kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ is Galois when we write "$G(\kappa(\mathfrak{P})\mid \kappa(\mathfrak{p}))$"?

One more thing: he writes $G(\kappa(\mathfrak{P})\mid \kappa(\mathfrak{p}))=G(\kappa(\mathfrak{p})(\overline{\theta})\mid \kappa(\mathfrak{p}))$, where $\overline{\theta}$ is a primitive element for the "maximal separable subextension". Why is that true?

Comment: Not every quotient of a Dedekind domain by a (nonzero) prime ideal is a finite field. This is true in the number field case, but not in general. (Think about the example of $K[X]$, where $K$ is a field, e.g.)

Comment: In the finite residue field case : the minimal polynomial is $f(x) = \prod_j (x-\sigma_j(\theta))^e$, the reduction of $f$ contains the minimal polynomial of $\bar{\theta}$ which is $\prod_l (x-\bar{\theta}^{q^l})$, thus there is some $\sigma_j$ such that $\sigma_j(\theta) \equiv \theta^q \bmod \mathfrak{P}$, show $\sigma_j\in D_\mathfrak{P}$, then follow Neukrich to deal with the general case when there is no such primitive element

Comment: @AlexWertheim, you're totally right, thank you

Comment: No problem. As for your last question, I don't have an answer, but I think it should somehow boil down to the idea that every field automorphism of $k(\mathfrak{P})$ over $k(\mathfrak{p})$ is determined by an automorphism of the maximal separable subextension. I don't have a proof for this (or even know if it's true), but I suspect some approximation of this is, and this is the content of Neukirch's observation. (It's true, for instance, that if $E/F$ is a purely inseparable extension, then any morphism of fields $F \to L$ has at most one extension $E \to L$.)